# Download file from a URL into a remote machine

Tags: python, sftp

I am looking at downloading a file from URL into remote machine directly.. Is this possible with python paramiko sftp?

Comment: You could try os and then use `wget`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Comment: #You can try urlretrieve like so
`import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the download script first to the remote machine and the execute it

**Example:**

```
import paramiko
host="hostname"
user="username"
#SSH Connection#
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys()
ssh.connect(host, username=user, password='password')

#Copy Script to Remote#
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put("localpath", "remotepath")
sftp.close()
#Close#

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("python " + "remotepath" + '/downloadfile.py')
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```

**or** you can call the wget command directly instead of using the download script.

**Example:**

```
import paramiko
host="hostname"
user="username"
#SSH Connection#
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys()
ssh.connect(host, username=user, password="password")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd download_folder; wget http://DOWNLOAD.URL")
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
```